# Get track user location when app is killed

Tags: swift, background, core-location

I am making an app with location in real time, when I get the location in the foreground and background I have no problem, but when I want to do the same with the app closed, I can never get it. Is there a way to do this?

This is how I have the location configured

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9mlC.png)